# Traveling from Bulgaria to Turkey by bus, Visa on arrival?

Tags: visas, schengen, turkey, indian-citizens, bulgaria

Turkey grants visa on arrival for Schengen visa holders. I'm guessing this should be at all entry ports, including roads. Just wanted to confirm that if I'm travelling by bus with a valid Schengen visa, I'll be able to get the visa at the border checkpost.

Comment: Do check with Turkish immigration authorities. An embassy or consulate should be able to tell you. In many countries that have visa on arrival it's unlike what you think available only in specific points of entry (usually international airports and ports handling a lot of cruise ships). I believe this is the case in Turkey as well, but not 100% certain.

Comment: Yes I'm not from Schengen but Australia and I've received at least four Turkish visas on entry at at least two Bulgarian border crossings as well as two Georgian border crossings. You'll probably have to pay. The visa is a sticker like a postage stamp that only takes up a small area. It has very similar "90 days out of 180 days" as a Schengen visa so it's good for multiple entries. **WOAH** I just noticed you're not from the Schengen region but just a Schengen visa holder? So I'm not sure which parts of my comment apply to you...

Comment: are you indian passport holder? I think in this case you can get also a single entry eVisa. For more information see https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/

Comment: I'm an Indian passport holder. That's awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Dirty-flow will you please convert your comment to an answer.. it is the right answer :)

Comment: @Dirty-flow Is e-visa accepted on all ports? I thought it works only at airports.

Comment: @AhmedHashim I have no personal experience, but on the website I see no restriction for airport use only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indian citizens are eligible for single entry [e-Visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/). You should apply for your e-Visa at least 24 hours before your departure.